# Multiple check box validation

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

I know how to validate a single checkbox, but what if I have multiple checkboxes and I am saving those values into an array in my database? I want the user to either select one or more check boxes, which pops an alert box.

Below is a snipet of the form and the validator I use. The rest of the form validates fine. I use asp to produce multiple check boxes, but stackoverflow isnt letting display it, so just let you know there is more than one box.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="j" value="<%=getcall_1_ary(jt)%>"/>
```

Javascript:

```
 if (document.addSC.j.checked == false ) {
   alert("Select Desired Job Type")
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
<script>
    function validateCheckBoxes() 
    {
        var isValid = false;
        //alert("Check if any checkbox is not checked..."); 
        var allRows = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (var i=0; i < allRows.length; i++) {
            if (allRows[i].type == 'checkbox' && allRows[i].name == '123') {
                if (allRows[i].checked == true) {
                       return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return isValid;
    }

    function submitBtn (){
        if (!validateCheckBoxes()){
            alert("no check box selected");
        }
        else 
            alert("one or more check box selected");
    }


</script>
```

HTML Part:

```
<form  method="get">
    <input type="checkbox" name="123" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="123" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="123" />
    <input type="button" value="submit" onClick="JavaScript:submitBtn();"/>
</form>
```

Check it now.

Comment: Note that this gets ALL the checkboxes on a page. You may want to get only the ones inside the form.

Comment: change `if (allRows[i].type == 'checkbox')` to `if (allRows[i].type == 'checkbox' && allRows[i].name == '123')` if you want checkboxes of the form only.

Comment: Thanks!

Now I just have to work out how to mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use JQuery to query the checkboxes then loop on them to ensure that at least one is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, DO VALIDATE YOUR INPUT DATA SERVER-SIDE. I read your question and it suggests that you don't, so this is my tip.

In addition, you can get all checked boxes with the name "j".

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var jChecks = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= checkboxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxes[i].name == "j" && checkbox[i].checked) {
        jChecks.push( checkboxes[i] );
    }
}
if (jChecks.length > 0) {
    alert('more then one selected!');
} else {
    alert('select some checkboxes!');
}
```